# call sql from another class for android app

Tags: android, sql

Hi
I have created a database for my application and i have added items to the database using methods from the database class. I am encountering a problem do when i try to execute a sql query in the other class(app.java), i need to reference a database and thats where im having the problem!

this is the sql query im trying to execute(in database.java)

```
public void getData(SQLiteDatabase db, String data){
    String sql =
        "SELECT permissions FROM genres WHERE name = "+data+";";
      db.execSQL(sql);
}
```

and this is how i am calling it(in app.java)

```
appData.getData(db, chosenGenre);
```

I just dont no what to put for the "db" part in `appData.getPermissions(db, chosenGenre);`

Does anyone know how to do this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You would typically use a `SQLiteOpenHelper` to create the database files (if necessary) and obtain a `SQLiteDatabase` object which is used to access the actual database (files on disk read by SQLite).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html

Here's a nice tutorial

http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/2010/08/04/android-database-tutorial/2/

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the code where you define the database manager 'db'! If you are using a database created outside the android device, you might get some help from this link: 
http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Also, I have found that it's best to frame all table names and supplied values in single quotes a la -

String sql = "SELECT permissions FROM 'genres' WHERE name = '" + data + "'";

Note that the semicolon is not required.